# Как сделать селектор с привязкой к файлу PHP?

Tags: php, javascript, html

Здравствуйте, как сделать селектор. Чтобы сначала был выбор стран, к стране были прикреплены определенные города. Далее при выборе города открывалось содержимое файла php привязанное к данному городу. Нужен полный цикл. Я могу не правильно объяснить, но вот для наглядности вопроса сделал видео, что я имею ввиду в вопросе `https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fSxKDltA9-E` может оно поможет раскрыть вопрос.
Спасибо заранее за вашу помощь, с уважением.

Нужно типо такого `http://codepen.io/ajaxray/pen/oBPbQe`  Но после последнего действия чтобы высвечивалось содержимое файла привязанного к городу.

Comment: Куда делись все знатоки и помощники?

Comment: [это называется «асинхронный javascript и xml» (сокр. ajax](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/AJAX)

Comment: У меня вот такой вопрос... В чем собственно проблема??? Воспользуйтесь `AJAX` и двумя селекторами... В первом храните список стран, человек выбирает нужную страну и на сервер через `AJAX` отправляется страна, а возвращается селектор городов этой страны. А после выбора города отправляете еще один `AJAX` запрос на те данные которые вам нужны. И вот вы хотите для каждого города создать php файл? Вы хоть представляете сколько городов в одной только России? Лучше будет создать БД для этих целей...

Comment: @Руслан для небольшого количества городов я привел в своем ответе пример, как того хотел автор (без использования БД), там достаточно одного php файла для хранения всех данных. этого хватит на основные города-миллионники, но если делать полный охват, то да, потребуется база данных. "Вы хоть представляете сколько городов в одной только России?" - в РФ немногим более 151 тыс. населенных пунктов)))

Comment: @Руслан Мне не все города нужны, а только те от которых летают самолеты. Буду использовать здесь https://aviareysi.ru

Comment: да даже если так... РФ очень много городов в которых есть аэропорт)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Подгружайте данные через AJAX. Если Вы имеете ввиду что-то, подобное поиску городов в VK, но там реализовано через AJAX запрос в БД.

Если же хотите брать из файла, то вешаете обработчик на изменение селектора страны. При его срабатывании делаете запрос в AJAX к PHP-файлу со списками городов (там выбираете нужную страну и отправляете список городов этой страны в ответе). В клиенте при получении ответа от сервера вставляете этот список в селектор с городами.

По брать из файла не самая лучшая идея, т.к. при хорошей детализации городов будет много. Вносите все геоданные в базу.

**Шаг 1**

Например, делаем AJAX-запрос через JQuery, где call.php - скрипт, который будет выдавать нам список городов, а data - это то, что мы передаем в PHP-скрипт (в данном случае требуется передать id страны, берем из селектора country_id). Пишем соответствующую функцию:

```
function getCities() {
    var data = { country_id: document.getElementById('country_id').value };
    $.post('/call.php', { data: data }, function(result) {
        ...
    });
}
```

**Шаг 2**

В PHP-файле выбираем нужный нам массив со списком городов (на основе данных data):

```
$country_id = isset($_POST['data']['country_id']) ? $_POST['data']['country_id'] : NULL;
...
if ($country_id == 1) $result = array(array('city_id'=>'1', 'city_name'=>'Москва'), array('city_id'=>'2', 'city_name'=>'Санкт-Петербург'));
else if ($country_id == 2) $result = array(array('city_id'=>'1', 'city_name'=>'Нью-Йорк'), array('city_id'=>'2', 'city_name'=>'Сан-Франциско'));
...
echo json_encode($result, true);
exit();
```

**Шаг 3**

Далее возвращаемся в наш клиент и после получения ответа от сервера парсим полученный JSON-массив, собираем html-код селектора и обновляем DOM.

```
$.post('/call.php', { data: data }, function(result) {
    result = JSON.parse(result);
    ...
    var html = '';
    result.forEach(function(data, index) {
        html += '<option value="' + data.city_id + '">' + data.city_name + '</option>';
    });
    document.getElementById('city_id').innerHTML = html;
});
```

Где document.getElementById('city_id') - наш селектор со списком городов, city_id - передаваемый в массиве айдишник города, а city_name - соответственно название города.

**Шаг 4**

В самом HTML уже должен быть код селекторов стран и городов. Селектор country_id статичный, селектор city_id собирается динамически в зависимости от выбора страны. Не забываем повесить на селектор country_id обработчик, который будет вызывать нашу JS-функцию с AJAX-запросом. А на селектор с выбором города (city_id) вешаем обработчик, который будет вызывать функцию открытия нужного файла.

```
<select id="country_id" onchange="getCities();">
    <option value="1">Россия</option>
    <option value="2">США</option>
    ...
</select>

<select id="city_id" onchange="openFile();"></select>
```

**Шаг 5**

В функции openFile() прописываем пути к файлам, которые будут открываться в зависимости от выбора города.

```
function openFile() {
    // vars
    var country_id = document.getElementById('country_id').value;
    var city_id = document.getElementById('city_id').value;
    // locations
    if (country_id == 1 && city_id == 1) window.location = 'https://aviareysi.ru/moscow.php';
    else if (country_id == 1 && city_id == 2) window.location = 'https://aviareysi.ru/peterburg.php';
}
```

Если городов достаточно много, то можно засунуть это в AJAX, но в самом простом варианте можно брать напрямую из JS-файла.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/59792/discussion-on-answer-by-dmitry-maslennikov-------).

Answer (score 4):

Все проще. Схема такова:

### Шаг 1:

Создаешь `<select></select>` добавляешь туда все города которые нужны. Создаешь папку `cities` и создаешь в ней сколько нужно `php` файлов с описанием городов.

### Шаг 2:

Добавляешь `<option value='имя_города'></option>`, (жеоаетльно чтобы плейсхолдер `имя_города` совпадал с именем файла с городом). Создаешь кнопку поиска.

### Шаг 3:

Создаешь `<iframe></iframe>` ниже и добавляешь такие скрипты в `JS` (я на jQuery)

```js
var currentCityValue;

$("select").change(function(){
  currentCityValue = $(this).val();
});

$("#searchButton").click(function(){
  $("iframe").attr("src", currentCityValue + ".php");
});
```

Так как я не знаю чего ты там удумал с эти делать, покажу на примере разных сайтов:

```js
var currentSiteValue;

$("select").change(function(){
  currentSiteValue = $(this).val();
});

$("#search").click(function(){
  $("iframe").attr("src", currentSiteValue);
});
```

```css
iframe {display: block; width: 400px; margin: 20px; height: 300px;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select>
<option value="0">Выберите сайт</option>
<option value="http://www.tinywebgallery.com/blog/advanced-iframe/free-iframe-checker">Site 1</option>
<option value="https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_iframe">Site 2</option>
</select>
<button id="search">Найти</button>

<iframe frameborder="1"></iframe>
```

Главное, чтобы на сайте не стояли "Header X-Frame-Options". Но думаю идею ты понял. Может она и не лучшая, но все таки юзабельная.

### UPDATE

Вот обещанный файл: [скачать тут](http://dropmefiles.com/hRwF2), если что вирусов нет.

Comment: Евгений, ваш вариант подходит, но сайт адаптирован под мобильники iframe c содержимым проблематично адаптировать и еще система такова Страна----->Город---->Вывод. В вашей системе пропущена Страна. А вариант мне нравится.

Comment: @Arcadiy Я могу попытаться сделать готовый файл уже и со странами и с городами, только страны будет где-то 2 и городов не очень много. А `iframe` можно адаптировать под мобильники, с помощью CSS + JS

Comment: Было бы супер, спасибо

Comment: @Arcadiy Я дополнил ответ (если конечно еще нужно).

Comment: Спасибо за Ваш ответ, но с адаптацией iframe под мобильные возникает проблема

Comment: @Arcadiy Ну тогда скорее всего надо flexbox в iframe юзать.